# Homology of iterated loop spaces on odd--dimensional spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

For prime $p$ let $E_p[\dots]$ and $P_p[\dots]$ be the external and polynomial $\mathbb{Z}_p$--algebras.

It is known that for $n\geqslant 1$ and odd $p$ where is an isomorphism
of primitively generated Hopf algebras
$H_*(\Omega^2S^{2n+1};\mathbb{Z}_p)=E_p[x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots]\otimes P_p[y_1,y_2,\dots]$
where $\deg(x_i)=2p^in-1$ and $\deg(y_i)=2p^in-2$.

For $p=2$ where is an isomorphism
of primitively generated Hopf algebras
$H_*(\Omega^2S^{2n+1};\mathbb{Z}_2)=P_2[z_0,z_1,z_2,\dots]$
where $\deg(z_i)=2^{i+1}n-1$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ How does a similar description of $H_*(\Omega^3S^{2n+1};\mathbb{Z}_p)$ looks like for $n\geqslant 2$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case where $n=dp$, the calculation of $H_*(\Omega^3S^{2n+1};\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is reviewed in Section 4.2 of the paper [The triple loop space approach to the telescope conjecture](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/mypapers/obit.pdf) by Mahowald, Ravenel and Shick.  I don't think that the assumption that $n=dp$ makes any real difference, although it will take a little work to straighten out all the indices for the general case.  All the real work is done in the book [Homology of iterated loop spaces](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf) by Cohen, Lada and May; the paper of Mahowald, Ravenel and Shick just spells out the simplifications that occur in the case at hand.

Comment: For anyone without a copy of Cohen-Lada-May, for $p$ odd and $n\geq2$ they calculate $H_*(S^{2n+1};\mathbb{F}_p)\cong\mathbb{F}_p[Q^a_{2(p-1)}u_{2n-2}\mid a\geq0]\otimes E(Q^a_{p-1}\beta Q^b_{2(p-1)}u_{2n-2}\mid a\geq0,b>0)\otimes \mathbb{F}_p[\beta Q^a_{p-1}\beta Q^b_{2(p-1)}u_{2n-2}\mid a,b>0]$

Comment: As has already been said, Cohen, Lada, May - see the part by Fred Cohen - has this and more. But this particular calculation (at least for p=2) goes back much further: Bill Browder's 1958 thesis, turned into a 1960 Illinois Journal of math article,  calculates precisely this, and introduces the `Browder operations' enroute.

Comment: @Tyrone: presumably you mean the homology of $\Omega^3 S^{2n+1}$, not the homology of $S^{2n+1}$.